# Developer license expiration

Tags: 8.1, microsoft-account

I am developing my application using free developer license which I have got in VS. This license have expiration date is one month after the date of issue.

I don't use Store and install app on our devices using power-shell script.

1. What will be with installed application after the license expire?
2. Is there any possibility to get developer license with expiration date more than 3 months?

Comment: If this question is off topic, then why close it instead of migrating it to the proper place?

Comment: @caschw, Indrek, Vitor Canova - I'm probably splitting hairs, but this is *not* a development question. The question is about a vendor program and licensing. Those questions are specifically off-topic at Stack Overflow. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to renew your license every month.
Maybe in the future you'll only have to renew it like once a every year.

Comment: I know it. The question is what will be with already installed application when the license will expire? It will stops working? Or it will be working fine, but I need the new license to update it?

Comment: It will be locked until you renew your license. It applies to VS Ultimate as well...